# Access SQL Server data mining result from C#

Tags: c#, machine-learning, business-intelligence, prediction, sql-server-data-tools

recently I have worked with MS Business Intelligence using SQL Server Data Tool. Using data mining functions of it, I managed to generate some prediction results base on history data.

Are there anyway I can get those result from C#? Like an dll that I can specify connection string, algorithm, some input variable then it will return a dataset of result?

Comment: Since the functionality available in MS SQL is neglibile anyway, consider using a real machine learning library instead.

Comment: SQL Server Reporting Services?